# Add delay to promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, timeout

I have the following class which generates Mock data. I would like to add a 2 second delay to simulate slow network. How can I add a timeout before returning the resolved promise?

Thanks,

```
export class MockGenerator {
    public getMockRecord = async () => {
        return Promise.resolve({id:123});
    };
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout`.